# Print Term ID in block on Term page?

Tags: 7

I have a block that displays on term pages. I need to print the term ID in this block.

I can see the term in the url (if I turn off pathauto) is something like this: mysite.com/bslb22/taxonomy/term/3

So is there some php that can get the ID from the url? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
// Make sure we are on the term page
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2)) {
  print arg(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways how to get that. You can use [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) or simpler [arg](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7).